# How to access a secured ArcGIS REST API using Python and extract the data in the form of Shapefiles or JSON

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, wfs, arcgis-rest-api

I have a secured ArcGIS REST API which requires username and password to access it. I am able to access a public service and extract the data in the form of shapefile. Below is my code,

```
import urllib2
import arcpy
import os

myurl="http://services.thelist.tas.gov.au/arcgis/rest/services/Public"
myservice="/TopographyAndRelief/MapServer"
myparams="/8/query?where=objectid%3E50+and+objectid%3C2001&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=&returnGeometry=true&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&returnIdsOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&f=pjson"
myRequest = myUrl + myService + myParams
myRequest = myurl + myservice + myparams
response = urllib2.urlopen(myRequest)
myJSON = response.read()
foo = open("C:\\Users\\venkatac\\Documents\\jsonOutput1.json", "wb")
foo.write(myJSON)
foo.close()
arcpy.JSONToFeatures_conversion("C:\\Users\\venkatac\\Documents\\jsonOutput1.json","C:\\Users\\venkatac\\Documents\\finalShapfile1.shp")
```

But I need to access a secured service using the credentials and extract the data.

Can anyone give me suggestions or any idea?

Comment: Have you done any research into using tokens?

Comment: Actually I have not tried...could you give me some help on it?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=arcgis+server+token

Comment: Is there any help or documentation on how to access the secured services using Python or Arcpy?

Comment: As the documentation found by googling indicates, it depends on *how* the website is secured. Have you *tried* to request a token? What was the result? Note that you should be using HTTPS when passing a password, and realy ought to be using POST for large/complex parameter lists. GIS SE works best when you provide a specific problem. Asking for documentation gives the impression that you're unwilling to follow up on leads and help yourself. This will not encourage others to help you.